# Rails 2.3.5: ActiveSupport CoreExtensions install trouble

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport

I get the following error "uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions" when trying to `ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Time::Conversions::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(
?>   :my_date => lambda { |time| time.strftime("%a, %b #{time.day.ordinalize}")`

All I'm trying to do is format dates in rails, but the bloody thing can't find Activesupport core extensions. I upgraded to latest version of rails and installs Active support from gems and I still get the same error.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm. Got it to work. All I had to do was reinstall active support via gems AND restart the server and console. That got it working. Hopefully this helps someone out there.